# I am getting an error when using flume

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, twitter

I am using the below configuration

```
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
ClouderaTwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type =   com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = Sully

ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/tweets
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
ClouderaTwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

ClouderaTwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
ClouderaTwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
ClouderaTwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

and this is the command that I am using to run flume

```
`bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume-cloudera.conf   -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n ClouderaTwitterAgent`
```

and this is the error that I am getting

```
    2016-09-20 14:53:14,245 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [DEBUG - com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource$1.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:121)] tweet arrived
 2016-09-20 14:53:16,073 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:234)] Creating hdfs://localhost:9000/user/tweets/FlumeData.1474363316543.tmp
 2016-09-20 14:53:16,113 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:459)] process failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:718)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:703)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:605)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2554)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2546)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2412)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:243)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:235)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:679)
at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:676)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:38)
... 26 more
2016-09-20 14:53:16,121 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor)  [ERROR-org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)]   Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
```

Can anyone please help me. I am new to this and I got this configuration from the internet and I followed every instruction.
I even searched for any solution to this problem.
I will list out what I have done 
1.I checked my system clock
2.removed the hdfs folder and then made a new folder
3.formatted the namenode
4.restarted the agent several times

Comment: where did you find the configuration? what did you follow?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example This is the link which I followed

Comment: i am not sure whether this help, but i have similar error. You can try to go to `/flume/conf` folder, create a copy of  `flume-env.sh` from the provided template, and within this `flume-env.sh` file add `export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Xms256m`. It solves my error on my linux machine.